# MongoDB update upon button click

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Within my view, I am directing the user from '/dashboard' to '/upvote'

Within my routes, I have:

```
app.get('/upvote', function(req, res) {
        user = req.user
        user.score += 1;
        user.save();
        res.redirect('/dashboard');
    });
```

This is just an example, trying to grasp how to use this for a different purpose at a later stage.

How do I correctly update my users 'score' attribute to increment every time there's a GET command for '/upvote/' ?

Comment: what are you using to connect to mongo? the native driver, mongoose,...?

Comment: Sorry, I'm using Mongoose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the given user in your request; req.user is just an object and not a mongoose model.  If you have the ID of the document, you can use findById.  If you don't you'll need to use a find query on another field.

```
// Users is the mongoose model
Users.findById(id, function (err, user) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);

  user.score += 1;

  user.save(function(err) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);
    res.send(user); // Or redirect, basically finish request.
  });
});
```

Second of all -  I wouldn't necessarily do a redirect.  You could stay on the same page and simply have the command refresh the user model.

Answer (score 1):

If you separately modify and then save your `user` document, you can lose votes during concurrent requests.

Instead, use [`update`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update) with the [`$inc`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/#up._S_inc) operator to make the upvote atomic:

```
app.get('/upvote', function(req, res) {
    User.update({_id: req.user._id}, {$inc: {score: 1}}, function(err, count) {
        res.redirect('/dashboard');
    });
});
```

BTW, you should consider using a POST or PUT request instead of a GET as GET requests shouldn't change data.